# How to make Tensorflow checkpoints compatible between minor versions when using tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, version, compatibility

I'm new to Tensorflow so I'm learning about model saving/loading schemes. I am working with a library which provides a model checkpoint (.index and .data files only) which was saved in Tensorflow 2.2. I would like to load this checkpoint using the same library but with Tensorflow 2.6 so that it may be run in Google Colab. When I load the checkpoint in Tensorflow 2.2 (with associated CUDA version), the model works fine. However, if I load the same checkpoint in Tensorflow 2.6 (with latest CUDA versions), the model runs without throwing any errors but the output is completely different.

To note, the library does make use of some experimental API's which may be responsible for the version compatibility issues (as noted in the official guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/versions#compatibility_of_graphs_and_checkpoints)). In particular, it uses *tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision.experimental* extensively, as well as *tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth*, *tf.data.experimental.copy_to_device*, and *tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE*. Intuitively, *mixed_precision.experimental* seems likely to significantly impact the weight saving/loading across minor versions.

I do receive the following warnings. They disappear if I switch to using *tf.keras.mixed_precision* (no experimental), however the model output is still completely wrong.

> WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/mixed_precision/loss_scale.py:52: DynamicLossScale.**init** (from tensorflow.python.training.experimental.loss_scale) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

> Instructions for updating: Use tf.keras.mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer instead. LossScaleOptimizer now has all the functionality of DynamicLossScale

> WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py:1361: NameBasedSaverStatus.**init** (from tensorflow.python.training.tracking.util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

> Instructions for updating: Restoring a name-based tf.train.Saver checkpoint using the object-based restore API. This mode uses global names to match variables, and so is somewhat fragile. It also adds new restore ops to the graph each time it is called when graph building. Prefer re-encoding training checkpoints in the object-based format: run save() on the object-based saver (the same one this message is coming from) and use that checkpoint in the future.

Any recommendations for saving a mixed_precision model checkpoint so that it is compatible across minor versions? Or dealing with experimental Tensorflow API's in general?

Comment: Could you train  the  earlier model in TF 2.6 and verify the difference  of output between generated check point and earlier checkpoint.